# Getting errorTemplate DoesNotExist while adding new page using new class (wagtail, django)

Tags: python, django, wagtail

The problem is that when creating a page using the new class, I get a TemplateDoesNotExist error.
Full error text:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /green-tea/

home/product.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://relizerel.pythonanywhere.com/green-tea/
Django Version:     3.0.4
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

home/product.html

Exception Location:     /home/relizerel/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version:     3.8.0
Python Path:    

['/home/relizerel/myshopwt',
 '/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/home/relizerel/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python38.zip',
 '/home/relizerel/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.8',
 '/home/relizerel/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/home/relizerel/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Server time:    Вт, 31 Мар 2020 02:25:43 +0200
```

My model.py file:

```py
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.core.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting

class HomePage(Page):
    pass

class Product(Page):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('sku'),
        FieldPanel('price'),
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('short_description'),
        InlinePanel('custom_fields', label='Custom fields'),
    ]

class ProductCustomField(Orderable):
    product = ParentalKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='custom_fields')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    options = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('options'),
    ]

@register_setting
class MushkinoSettings(BaseSetting):
    api_key = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        help_text='Ваш публичный ключ API Мушкино'
    )
```

My base.py (settings.py) file:

```py
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'search',

    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail.core',

    'modelcluster',
    'taggit',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'wagtail.contrib.settings'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myshopwt.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myshopwt.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'relizerel$myshopwt',
        'USER': 'relizerel',
        'PASSWORD': '1590753Aa',
        'HOST': 'relizerel.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kaliningrad'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]

# ManifestStaticFilesStorage is recommended in production, to prevent outdated
# Javascript / CSS assets being served from cache (e.g. after a Wagtail upgrade).
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Wagtail settings

WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = "myshopwt"

# Base URL to use when referring to full URLs within the Wagtail admin backend -
# e.g. in notification emails. Don't include '/admin' or a trailing slash
BASE_URL = 'http://example.com'
```

Please tell me how to fix this error?
What data should be provided?
if this is a stupid question - please tell me, where can I find out more on this issue?

Comment: Added an answer. do you have the `templates/home/product.html` file in your project? If so, show us your project directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for the `templates/home/product.html` template file. You should have this in your project.

Comment: This file is not in the folder. Do I need to create this file myself or using wagtail?

Comment: I created this file myself. Now the page opens without problems. Now I will fill this page with content Thanks

Comment: Great to hear, if you want to read more about it, you can check https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/topics/writing_templates.html